# Orion theme (from theme forest)

Tags: themes, installation, css

I was given a theme called Orion available from themeforest. I had experienced troubles installing it via GUI (style.css was missing), therefore I did that operation manually by copying Update directory up the directory tree.

Now the theme appears somehow empty/broken. I was wondering whether this specific theme is meant to be standalone or just as an update to a prerequired theme (and which one, if this is the case).

Thank you!

Edit: I apologize as I wasn't clear enough. Is it normal that the theme .zip file which should be used to install the theme does not contain style.css? Why is the stylesheet only included in Update folder and what is (usually) the purpose of that subfolder?

Comment: please explain more, didn't get you.

Comment: Best place to ask is the support forums of the theme author

Comment: It's unlikely that it was a child theme, requiring another theme for functionality and styling.

You indicated that you were "given" the theme. The theme authors generally provide some level of support, if you have actually purchased the product. If you don't have the license, you're on your own.

Comment: I would like to thank everyone on trying to help me out. It just seems that I was only provided with some kind of update by my employer, thus I will need to request the full theme. The whole confusion arose as I wasn't doing anything WP related before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every WordPress theme, including child themes, is required to have a `style.css` file.  The first few lines in `style.css` tell WordPress the name of the theme, the description, and some other meta information about the theme.

You'll have to ask the theme developer why there are files missing in your theme.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've tried to upload the incorrect file. You will need to firstly unzip the file from themeforest and then there should either be another .zip file inside (I'm guessing called Orion.zip) or possibly a folder called 'Orion'...?

You will need to upload the theme .zip file within the main .zip file in order to install. However, as Mark Kaplun has said also, it's probably best to contact the theme author and this should usually be detailed in the theme instructions.

If you're still stuck, please provide full list of the files which are in the .zip file you tried uploading when you got the error 'style.css missing'.

Ps. The 'update' folder is theme specific and it's purpose would depend on the theme.